# Subtracting two images in Computer Vision

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, imagefilter

I have been working on computer vision and openCV (C++)
I applied a filter

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

on an image and got the result image_result.

I took the difference :

```
image_result - image.
```

But I found a couple of programs where the subtraction is done this way:

```
    image_result - image + image - image_result
```

Can someone give me an idea why the subtraction is done in the above mentioned way and Is it the right way to find the difference between two images?

Thank you

Comment: Could you link these resources that you're mentioning?

Comment: ` image_result - image + image - image_result` would give you a blank image wouldn't it? The subtractions all cancel out.

Comment: @nellorocca I am sorry. I meant I saw a few codes in github.

Comment: @immibis No they don't cancel out. I do get an output

Comment: Depends on the data type whether you get an output. But in any case, as mentioned by Cris, I'm not sure if I prefer the three additions/subtractions over the abs and one subtraction. So many operations seems worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is specifically for unsigned pixels and using saturation arithmetic, where subtraction that leads to a negative number yields 0 instead. The first subtraction gives you the values where the result is larger, the second one where the result is smaller. The result would be equivalent to `abs(image-image_result)` if using normal, signed arithmetic.